# What is the form of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis

This is part of a theorem relating to conformal maps in Freitag's Complex Analysis
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ad-bc \ge 0$ and $ac+db=0 \Rightarrow d=-\frac{ac}{b}$ thus 
$$a\left( -\frac{ac}{b} \right)-bc\ge0 \Rightarrow (a^2+b^2)\frac{-c}{b}\ge0$$
which results in the fact that $b$ and $c$ have different signs such that $-\frac{c}{b}\ge0$. The same reasoning for $b=-\frac{ac}{d}$ gives $(d^2+c^2)\frac{a}{d}\ge0$ and thus $\frac{a}{d}\ge0$ which means $a$ and $d$ have the same sign. Therefore is general the statement is false, only the signs need to obey the above rules, $a=d$ and $b=-c$ are just a special case.

We conclude that matrix is of the form

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & c  \\
    -cm & \frac{a}{m}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $m \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $a,c \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: thanks, I just now got a counter example

Comment: can it be similar to a matrix of the form i mentioned?

Comment: Ummm, by similar you mean is there an invertible matrix $P$ such that $M=PAP^{-1}$ and $M$ described as above $a=d$ and $b=-c$? I mean, can you define similarity?

Comment: If detM>0 and ac+bd=0, then can it be similar to matrix A, where A(1,1)=A(2,2) and A(1,2)=-A(2,1)